# topsy otter api: exact phrase match (multiple words)

Tags: api, search, twitter, topsy

i am evaluating topsy's otter api. does anybody know a good way for getting right results for exact phrases like "online internet course" (exotic term).

http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?apikey=(your-api-key)&q=%22online%20internet%20course%22&perpage=100&nohidden=0&mintime=315532800

this will return results containing all words, but not the exact pharse. thus it will also match "online internet marketing course".

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need to use the double quotes (%22) on either end, but you also need to use a '+' (%2B) between words, instead of a space (%20).

Comment: thanks for your reply.

even using this url 

http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?apikey=(your-api-key)&q=%22online%2Binternet%2Bcourse%22&perpage=100&nohidden=0&mintime=315532800

i get the inexact results like: 
"for the internet age. This (free) online course management"

current strategy to get exact matches is:
1. assume that exact matches are before inexact in the result (perhaps score can be used).
2. search results for exact phrase and kill results wihout phrase.